# Jenkins pipeline groovy code execution context

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I would like to clarify, whether groovy code from scripted pipeline, or from `script` step in DSL, or within `node` step, or from shared libraries <s>(or any combination of these)</s> are being executed on agent, not master JVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any code that you run inside a `node` block (or have an `agent` block in a `stage` for declarative pipeline) will run exclusively on said node.

Other code runs in the master node. That includes:

- Anything outside a `node` block / steps with `agent none` in declarative pipeline
- Code marked with `@NonCPS`
- A `node` block that specifically asks for the master label (don't do that of course)